# How to divide sending info different blade template

Tags: laravel-5

I have this auto email reply function. It works fine.

Currently To (User email address) and BCC (Webmaster email address) receive the same blade template as mail/temp.

I would like to make them separate title and body message. I created `temp_admin.blade.php` for webmaster. I've been adjust this code but always error show up. Here is my code. Could you teach me how to write separately?

```
public function complete()
{
      $data = session()->all();
      Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.temp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message->to($data["email"])->bcc('admin@test.sakura.ne.jp')
    ->from('support@test.sakura.ne.jp')->subject('Thank You');});   

    $data = session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('mail.complete');
}
```

I add this code

```
Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.admintemp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message->to('lara_admin@test.sakura.ne.jp')
->from('support@test.sakura.ne.jp')->subject('This is for admin');});
```

Comment: First of all, if you send an email to someone and put someone in BCC. that sends exactly an identical email copy to the BCC list. What you're trying to achieve is not like the actual behavior. right?

Comment: Dear @ssi-anik Thank you for answering me. Yes totaly you are right. I've forget BCC mean. but actually I've already tried make another TO as admin email address but it comes error... and I backed this code. Do me a faover Could you teach me how to adjust please?

Comment: Is everything okay w/o the bcc part? if yes, you can just do the same code for the bcc. And, it'll be a good idea to make a class that takes the receivers and template/values and only shoots those email. probably that's called the DRY. don't do the same thing twice.

Comment: Dear @ssi-anik Thank you very much your support. Now I success what I wanted. Thank you. I wrote extra code like this above? Is this Okay? for my skill I can't make smart way that I will study for future. but for now . Could you teah me Is this okay code?

Comment: Seems okay. Remove the first BCC if you don't want to receive two emails.

Comment: Dear @ssi-anik  Thank you so much. I would like to give up vote. so Could you make answer? than I can do it. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for being so generous. The comments solved the issue. Rather you can also answer your question. And it'll help others. I didn't actually do anything in here. So can't post an answer. Happy coding.

Comment: Dear @ssi-anik You are the best! I never forget your many help. Thank you very much.